# How to stop excel from displaying 3-letter months

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, date, date-format

I am running Excel (Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO Version 2211) on Windows 10.

Whenever I enter a date without a year into a cell, Excel displays the month as 3-letter abbreviations instead of numbers.

Example: If I enter "4/22", Excel displays it as "22-Apr".  I don't want it to do that.  I want it to display as "4/22", like I entered it.

According to [this Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e), I need to change this in Windows Control Panel, but it doesn't say what actual setting to change.  I've tried going into "Time & Language" -> "Region", but I can't find a setting that affects this particular situation.

What exactly do I need to change?

I know that I can reformat dates after entering them, or for ranges of cells, but I don't want to have to do that every time.  I want to change the default for new workbooks.

Comment: It seems can not be achieved via Control Panel settings. I tried go to Additional Settings > Date tab, change the shord date to be 'M/d', but it does not work.

Comment: Change the cell type to pure text, and Excel should stop changing it. Alternatively, precede each entry with single quote (apostrophe).

Answer (score 0):

Pre-format the cell(s) using a date format you prefer.

Now when you put data into the cells, Excel will not "guess" how you want to display it since you already told it beforehand.

Generally, Excel behaves better when you pre-format it to say which cells are text, numbers, dates etc. Leaving everything formatted as "General" makes Excel guess your intentions, so it will not always get this right. (another example would be dropping leading zeroes from phone numbers if you do not pre-format them as text)

Comment: I actually WANT them to be date fields, not text.  I just don't want it to format them like "22-Apr" by default for new workbooks/sheets/etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So format them as date fields but in a date format you want. Excel can display date in many different ways. If you choose to display them as m/dd by formatting the empty cell first, then when you enter your data it won't change to a different format. You don't have to format as text or add an apostrophe in front, because, as you say, that means it is no longer an actual date.

Comment: Yes, I already knew that I could do that.  What I was wanting to do is to change the DEFAULT for new workbooks/sheets/cells, so that it would defalut to the 4/22 format without me having to pre-format the cells every time.  That is the format that I pretty much always want for my workbooks.  The Microsoft article that I linked to in my original question seems to say that it can be done via Control Panel, but lacks sufficient details of how to do it.